# Sort the effective way to show hide result div typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typehead

I need help to optimize (algorithm) show-hide element based on Javascript triggered by jQuery Plugin Typehead.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    var cars = ['apv', 'celerio', 'dreza', 'ertiga', 'ertiga diesel', 'futura', 'ignis', 'swift', 'sx4', 'vitara', 'wagon'];            
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;
        matches = [];
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
        $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                matches.push(str);
            }
        });
        cb(matches); 
        //show - hide result function
        showresult(matches,cars);
        };
    };

    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,
        limit: 4
    },
    {
        name: 'cars',
        source: substringMatcher(cars)
    });

    // Here is my function
    function showresult(strs,cars) {    
        var count =  cars.length;
        var countx = strs.length;
        var temp = '';
        $('.product-index').hide(); 
            for (j = 0; j < countx; j++) {
                for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    if (cars[i] == strs[j]) {                               
                    temp = '';                              
                    temp = '.' + cars[i]; 
                    temp = temp.replace(' ','-');
                    $(temp).show();     
                    }
                }
            }
    }
});
```

The HTML div looks like this

```
<div class="product-index ertiga-diesel">
<!-- the content -->    
</div>
```

Is this already optimized enough? I'm worried about too much looping when having a lot of data that would come from a remote database.

Comment: If it is already working, it would be better to put this on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: OMG, i don't know there is "codereview", my bad.